# ISO 8583 create LLLLVAR

Tags: c, pos, iso8583, jpos

Is it possible to use a field more than 999 bytes in ISO8583?

I wanna to send data in a filed which has more than 999 bytes. What is the best solution?
Can I define a new type: LLLLVAR to do that? I think we are enable to do that in JPOS but I cannot find it in [WIKI_ISO8583](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8583).

Note that I used an specialized library to do that in c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, as long as you agree with the other party the length of the length field.

In ISO8583, V2003 there are some fields defined as LLLLVAR  such as DE 34 and 43 defined also in jPOS CMF.

I'm not sure it's defined in v87 of ISO8583 since I don't have the spec,  which is on what the Wikipedia page is based on.

Either way the Wikipedia page is not fully comprehensive on the standard.